# USING IF statement inside the CASE in P/L SQL ?

Tags: plsql

```
DECLARE
       H EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
       F EMP.ENAME%TYPE;
       D NUMBER;
       S VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
       H := :ENTER_A_DEPTNO;
       SELECT ENAME, EMPNO INTO F , D
       FROM EMP
       WHERE EMPNO = H;
    CASE
        WHEN D = H THEN
        S := F;
        WHEN D != H THEN
        S := ' NO DATA !!';
     END CASE; 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(S);
END;
```

when i put any number ID not from the table it's not working with the second if statement . I'm wondering how to display the message ?

```
ORA-01403: no data found
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Nice formatted question! Just one thing: you speak of `IF`, but the code does not have a single `IF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `exception` block:

```
DECLARE
       H EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
       F EMP.ENAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
       H := :ENTER_A_DEPTNO;
       SELECT  ENAME INTO F
         FROM  EMP
         WHERE EMPNO = H;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(F);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' NO DATA !!');
END;
```

There is no need for an `if` or `case`, because when the value was found, you can be sure the result concerns the correct employee number. If not found, the exception is raised, and execution is diverted to the `EXCEPTION` block.